# latitude and longitudes under stereographic projection

Tags: complex-analysis

I completed reading about Stereographic Projection today.

We know there are latitude and longitudes drawn on a globe(which is a sphere). I was wondering where the lines of latitude and longitude are mapped to under streographic projection.

Although I am not able to write a proof but it looks like( I just created a mental image) lines of longitude are mapped to straight lines.

and lines of latitude are mapped to circles centered to zero.

Am I right?

If yes, how can I prove it mathematically.

Comment: I read in Gamelin, that projection of every longitude is a straight line passing through $(0,0)$ in complex plane.

Comment: And projection of every latitude is a circle centered at $(0,0)$ in complex plane. In particular, the projection of equator is the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$ in complex plane.

Comment: But how can we prove it mathematically @spkakkar

Comment: I was just telling that passing through origin is mandatory. Had I known, I would have answered, instead of comment :P

Comment: @spkakkar Thanks for the ref. I would go through the book and let you know if I am able to write a proof..

Comment: Working out the geometry by hand isn't too bad. Just some triangles. And to answer your question, yes, latitudes are mapped to lines and longitudes to circles. Generalized circles (lines being circles of infinite radius) are mapped to generalized circles - you can verify this by considering the formula for a circle (arguably easier if you think of the sphere as the one point compactification of $\mathbb C$)